# Xamarin Forms How to update an image on screen after a variable behind has been set to a different value?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I would like to update the image that is being displayed on my screen after the behind code has changed the `ImageSource` value. I have tried sing `INotifyPropertyChnage` but this doesn't seem to work idk if this is just me.

```
public string ImageSource
{
    get => _ImageSource;
    set
      {
         if (_ImageSource == value)
             return;

           _ImageSource = value;
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ImageSource)));
       }
 }
```

This my my `GameLoop` method which assigns the values

```
private async Task GameLoop(int maxWordsInCurrentGame)
{
     for (int i = 1; i <= maxWordsInCurrentGame; i++)
     {
          var gameResources = GetSourcesFromConfig(CurrentGame, i, true, true, true, true, true, true, false);
          _ImageSource = gameResources["image"];
          _MediaSource = gameResources["video"];
           await Task.Delay(10000);
      }

   CurrentGame += 1;
   StartGame();
 }
```

I currently only have it to await 10 seconds to change the image but it doesn't happen.

I'm using `DataBinding` for my `XAML` front code

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"
               BackgroundColor="White"
               Grid.Row="1"
               VerticalOptions="Start"
               HeightRequest="75"
               Margin="0, 20, 0, 0"
               Aspect="AspectFill"/>
```

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: I think you should update **ImageSource** instead of **_ImageSource**.

Comment: Thank you so much @DineshFalwadiya that was the issue it is now updating as needed. I've spent way too long on this god damm :).

Comment: Haha, I also used to spend a lot of time on small mistakes. Happy to help you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's the wrong property you are updating:

```
public string ImageSource
{
    get => _ImageSource;
    set
      {
         if (_ImageSource == value)
             return;

           _ImageSource = value;
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ImageSource)));
       }
 }
```

You could write the code like that then it would be obvious to update "**ImageSource**" instead of the "***_imageSource***".

```
string _imageSource
public string ImageSource
{
    get => _imageSource;
    set
      {
         if (_imageSource == value)
             return;

           _imageSource = value;
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(_imageSource)));
       }
 }
```